# move_uploaded_file() working on localhost but on server

Tags: php

The following code works perfect on my localhost but it shows the following errors on my live server

**Warning:** move_uploaded_file(.../uploads/76948893.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

**Warning:** move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phppxvRs8' to '.../uploads/76948893.jpeg'

What it does is simple, it takes the images on the array ["pictures"] which comes from a html form and save every image on the folder ".../uploads/" using a random numeric name as name of the file and keeping the original extension.

Any one knows how to make it work on my server?

```
   //Image Uploader
    $images=[];
    $directory = '.../uploads/';
    foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        $new_file_name = rand (10000000,99999999);
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
       /* echo '<br>';
        echo $directory.$new_file_name.".".substr($_FILES['pictures']['type'][$key],strpos($_FILES['pictures']['type'][$key], "/")+1);*/

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name'][$key], 
                            $directory
                            .$new_file_name
                            .".".substr($_FILES['pictures']['type'][$key],strpos($_FILES['pictures']['type'][$key], "/")+1)))               {
            array_push($images,$new_file_name.".".substr($_FILES['pictures']['type'][$key],strpos($_FILES['pictures']['type'][$key], "/")+1));
            $images_validator=true;
        }else{
        //Error
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What @Fred-ii- said, and try absolute path instead of a relative path. (Change `$directory` to `$directory = getcwd() . 'uploads/';`)

Comment: plus, you'll want to change `.../` to `../` 2 dots not 3.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Folder permissions sounds like that might be the problem but I have set the folder permissions from my ftp to rwxrwxrwx and still shows the same problem... is there any other way to set the permissions? (Im new on this...)

(3 dots are ok because that is where the uploads folder is)

Comment: My bad! you where right about the 2 dots! Thank you Fred for both right answers!

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reason for this, Check the following

1. You need WRITE Permission for the `uploads` directory. I assume your local machine runs windows & your hosting environment is linux
2. Like @Darren suggests, use absolute path. change the `$directory` to `$directory = getcwd() . 'uploads/';`

Answer (score 0):

If this runs on your local machine but not on server there are 2 easy answers I can think off right off the back. 1. The folder doesnt exist on the server, 2. as someone comment you dont have permission to write/read to that folder on the server....I would check the server configuration to make sure your app pool or users have read/write permissions to the folder